# Borders are cropped with rounded corners? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, border, rounded-corners

I've seen a few questions on this subject, but they are only answers one of the problems. I'm rounding corners from one side by:

```
func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.layer.mask = mask
}
```

and implementation:

```
detailsView.roundCorners(.allCorners, radius: 20)
```

Then, I'm trying to add borders by:

```
func addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge, color: UIColor, thickness: CGFloat) {

    let border = CALayer()

    switch edge {
        case UIRectEdge.top:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: thickness)

        case UIRectEdge.bottom:
            border.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: frame.height - thickness, width: frame.width, height:thickness)

        case UIRectEdge.left:
            border.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: thickness, height: frame.height)

        case UIRectEdge.right:
            border.frame = CGRect(x: frame.width - thickness, y: 0, width: thickness, height: frame.height)

        default: do {}
    }

    border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    addSublayer(border)
}
```

and implementation:

```
detailsView.layer.addBorder(edge: .top, color: .lightLavender, thickness: 1)
```

What am I doing wrong? I get this result – borders are cropped:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've rounded top corners by:

```
func roundCorners(radius: CGFloat, mask: CACornerMask) {
    cornerRadius = radius
    maskedCorners = mask
```

Implementation:

```
    detailsView.layer.roundCorners(radius: 20, mask: [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner])
```

Borders:

```
extension UIView {
@IBInspectable var borderWidthV: CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.borderWidth
    }
    set {
        layer.borderWidth = newValue
    }
}

@IBInspectable var borderColorV: UIColor? {
    get {
        return UIColor(cgColor: layer.borderColor!)
    }
    set {
        layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor
    }
  }
}
```

And after that, I've just added white UIView to the bottom of my view to hide bottom borders.

Answer (score 0):

`self.layer.masksToBounds = true` make the border cropped.

You have to use two views one inside another to solve this problem. Also set the frame identical for both of the views.

In child view use

```
childView.roundCorners(.allCorners, radius: 20)
```

In parent view use

```
parentView.layer.addBorder(edge: .top, color: .lightLavender, thickness: 1)
```